# Unable to write data on realtime database of firebase using kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val imageurl = imageurlset.text.toString()
        val venue = venueset.text.toString()
        val date = dateset.text.toString()

        event_btn.setOnClickListener {
            saveuserinfo(imageurl, venue, date)       }
    }

    private fun saveuserinfo(imageurl: String, venue: String, date: String) {
        val usersRef: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("event")
        val adminRef: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("NewData")

        val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
        userMap["imageurl"] = imageurl
        userMap["venue"] = venue
        userMap["date"] = date



        usersRef.child(date).setValue(userMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                adminRef.child(date).setValue(userMap)
                    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                baseContext, "Success",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                baseContext, "error.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

This is my mainActivity. I want to write data on realtime database using this code. I have already created database. I have url of my images. I am just unable to connect them with realtime database.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
```

These are my dependencies.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

These are my rules for realtime database. Please help me with this.

Comment: Is any of the Toast messages displayed?

Comment: error is shown.

Comment: Have you tried to log the message inside the Exception object?

Comment: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Comment: setValue at /NewData failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Comment: There is no authentication method in my project. I don't want user to log in.

Comment: If you get "DatabaseError: Permission denied", then you should configure the correct rules.

Comment: Can you please tell me the changes in my rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another similar project and it worked out for me. I don't know the problem in my project but now my new project is working fine.